# Poll second URL until JSON returns an expected parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm using a travel API which I first hit with a request to create a session and then I use the session URL returned from that URL to then call until its status parameter returns `UpdatesComplete`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
lateinit var pollUrl: String
travelInteractor.createSession("LHR", "AKL", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-22")
.doOnSubscribe {
    loading.postValue(true)
}
.flatMap { url ->
    pollUrl = url
    travelInteractor.pollResults(pollUrl)
    .retryWhen {
        it.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
}
.doOnNext {
    if (it.status != "UpdatesComplete") travelInteractor.pollResults(pollUrl)
         .retryWhen {
             it.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         }
}
.subscribe({
     // Subscription stuff
)}
```

What's currently happening is that it will call `doOnNext()` and then it will make the network poll but I won't be capturing the subscription and also won't chain another poll. Is there a more efficient way I can be writing this?

---

**Solution**

Thanks to `iagreen` I managed to achieve this with:

```
lateinit var pollUrl: String
travelInteractor.createSession("LHR", "AKL", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-22")
.doOnSubscribe {
    loading.postValue(true)
}
.flatMap { url ->
    travelInteractor.pollResults(url)
    .retryWhen {
        it.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
    .repeatWhen {
        it.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
    .filter {
        it.itineraries.map { ... } // Use response here appropriately and then check status
        it.status == "UpdatesComplete"
    }
    .take(1)
}
.subscribe({
     // Subscription stuff
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `pollResults(url)` method returns a `Single` or an `Observable` that behaves like a single -- it returns one result and then `onComplete`.  If that is truly the case, you can use `repeatWhen` to retry the request on success and `retryWhen` to retry on error.  See the code below.

```
skyScannerInteractor.createSession("LHR", "AKL", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-22")
    .doOnSubscribe {
        loading.postValue(true)
    }
    .flatMap { url ->
        skyScannerInteractor.pollResults(url)
            .repeatWhen { complete -> complete.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) } 
            .retryWhen { errors -> errors.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
            .filter({ it.status == "UpdatesComplete" })
            .take(1)  // Take the first valid value and complete
    }
    .subscribe({
         // Subscription stuff
    )}
```

A little explanation -

- `repeatWhen/retryWhen` will try the request every second.
- `filter` will cause elements with the wrong status to be ignored.
- When you get the first `status == "UpdatesComplete"` element, `take(1)` will emit that value and complete -- this will have the effect of cancelling the retries.

**Note:**  In the case of an error, retrying a network request forever is usually the wrong thing to do.  I recommend you modify the `retryWhen` above to suit you use case to terminate in the event of network failure. For example, you could retry three times and then propagate the error. See [this article](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) for some examples on how you could do that.  It is also a good reference on `repeatWhen/retryWhen`.

Comment: I needed to use the data that comes in when the status returns as pending so within the filter I use that data. Otherwise perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`retry()` and `retryWhen()` both respond to an onError event in the Observable, that is why it isn't actually retrying; you're not receiving those onError events in your `pollResults()` Observable. Right now, your retrying code doesn't actually depend on the JSON response.

There are two ways I would think about going about this:

1. Throw an exception in your `pollResults()` Observable if the JSON response is unsatisfactory. This should trigger the `retryWhen()`. You'll need to test for it in the Observable somewhere.
2. Reorganize your Observable like this:

`

```
lateinit var pollUrl: String
skyScannerInteractor.createSession("LHR", "AKL", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-22")
.doOnSubscribe {
    loading.postValue(true)
}
.flatMap { url ->
    pollUrl = url
    skyScannerInteractor.pollResults(pollUrl)    
}
.doOnNext {
    if (it.status != "UpdatesComplete") {
         throw IOException("Updates not complete.") //Trigger onError
     }
}
.retryWhen { //Retry the Observable (createSession) when onError is called         
    it.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
.subscribe({
    // Will give result only when UpdatesComplete
}
```